# ClassLoader in Singleton Pattern

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

I have come across this point while i have explored Singleton Pattern

> If the Singleton class is loaded by 2 different class loaders we'll
>   have 2 different classes, one for each class loader.

I dont know how two class loader will available for a JVM and how to come it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ClassLoaders are commonly encountered in Java EE. The Java EE application servers loads classes from deployed War/EAR by a tree of classloaders. The reason why they do it in this way is to isolate one application from other applications but still sharing classes between deployed modules. If you want your class to be truly singleton then you need to make sure that same classloader loads your singleton. You can achieve it like this

```
private static Class getClass(String clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      if(loader == null)
         loader = YourSingleton.class.getClassLoader();
      return (loader.loadClass(clazz));
   }
}
```

Note Enum in java already implement singleton pattern.

**Updated** Can you please explain what is multiple class Loader and how it resolve the issue.

Let say you have a library `Foo`. Some part of your project requires `Foo_version1.jar` and some other part requires `Foo_version2.jar`. So in your `classpath` you have `Foo_version1.jar` and `Foo_version2.jar`. Now the class loader need to load a class `Bar` from `Foo`, it will load it from first `Foo_versionX` that it finds on the `classpath`. In order to resolve this issue you need another class loader because remember that some part of your project require `Bar` class from different `jar` then the one loaded by classloader.

By using the code mentioned above you are making sure that if more than 1 classloader try to load your class then always the same instance will be used.

Comment: Can you please explain what is multiple class Loader and how it resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please tell where we need to add the block of code